# Return a List of links in reddit using PHP

Tags: php, reddit

Just wondering if someone has sample code to return the top 25 links of reddit (using PHP). In JSON or XML. i can't wrap my head around the API... and rarely use python.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$array = (array) json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.reddit.com/.json"));
```

That will return a PHP array with all the data from the front page. You can limit how many you display using a simple while() loop.

This is very simple now that you have the array from above, because all you have to do is step through it.

Comment: This works thank you. Just having troubles digging into such deep arrays in php. For example the first title is here.

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [kind] => t3 [data] => stdClass Object ( [domain] => imgur.com [banned_by] => [media_embed] => stdClass Object ( ) [subreddit] => funny [selftext_html] => [selftext] => [likes] => [link_flair_text] => [id] => x2gx8 [clicked] => [title] => What are you doing? 

any quick tips to get it? Thanks